# How can I avoid a "time limit exceeded" error in a code challenge environment?

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a Hackerrank question called "[Xor-sequence]"(https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/xor-se/problem).

I had used the logic that xor of same number is 0.

My code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef long long int ll;
int main()
{
ll q;    
scanf("%lld",&q);
for(int a=0;a<q;a++)
{
ll l,r,res=0;scanf("%lld%lld",&l,&r);
        if((r-l+1)%2==0)
        {
            for(ll i=l+1;i<=r;i+=2)
                res^=i;
        }
        else
        {
            for(ll i=l+1;i<r;i+=2)
                res^=i;
            for(ll i=0;i<=r;i++)
                res^=i;
        }
        printf("%lld\n",res);
    }
}
```

How can I simplify my logic in order to avoid hitting the time-limit?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: The posting guidelines tell you to "make it easy for others to help you".  We expect your question to be self-contained: giving us an off-site link to source material is generally not acceptable.  You failed to give a clear failing case.  Your code depends on external data, instead of being a stand-alone example.  The meaningless variable names leave your code hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this question can be done using the analogy of Prefix XOR.

Storing the answers in the array `dp` and computing answer for query `l r` by `dp[r] ^ dp[l-1]` where `^ = bitise XOR operation`

**Have a look at the following code:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
typedef long long int LL;
using namespace std;

LL dp[1000001];

int main(){

    dp[0] = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<(int)1e5;i++){
        dp[i] = dp[i-1]^i;
    }

    for(int i=1;i<(int)1e5;i++){
        dp[i] ^= dp[i-1];
    }

    int Q;
    cin >> Q;
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < Q; a0++){
        LL  L;
        LL R;
        cin >> L >> R;
        cout<<(dp[L-1LL]^dp[R])<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Time Complexity: O(|size of input|) + O(|# queries|)**

**Space complexity: O(|size of input|)**

**But, you can clearly have a look at the input constraints for which computations and required intermediate values cannot be accommodated in an array.**

**So, we need to further tweak our solution by observation.**

**The advantage we have here is the array on which we are querying our results is not changing. There we go!!! You go it!!**

Have a look at the array `dp` which stores prefix xors:

**dp  = 0 1 2 2 6 7 0 0 8 9 2 2 14 15 0 0 16 17 2 2 22 23 0 0 24 25 2 2 30 31 0**

Now, we therefore generalise the value of dp at any index by following using the following function:

```
LL getValue(LL n)
{
    LL dp[9];
    dp[0] = dp[1] = n;
    dp[2] = dp[3] = 2LL;
    dp[4] = dp[5] = n+2LL;
    dp[6] = dp[7] = 0LL;

    return dp[n%8];
}
```

And this forms the base for our entire solution.

Have a look at the final optimised code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
typedef long long int LL;
using namespace std;

LL getValue(LL n)
{
    LL dp[9];
    dp[0] = dp[1] = n;
    dp[2] = dp[3] = 2LL;
    dp[4] = dp[5] = n+2LL;
    dp[6] = dp[7] = 0LL;

    return dp[n%8];
}
int main(){

    int Q;
    cin >> Q;
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < Q; a0++){
        LL  L;
        LL R;
        cin >> L >> R;
        cout<<(getValue(L-1LL)^getValue(R))<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Time Complexity: O(|# queries|)**

**Space complexity: O(some constant)**

Answer (score 2):

When you approach a competitive programming task, before you start writing any code, you have to design an algorithm, and consider its time complexity. The time limit you are given is usually going to be quite short, so you should learn what time complexity your algorithm will have to be to pass the time limit on the platform you are using, depending on the input size. For HackerRank's judge, the following is a rough guide:

- n ~ 20: almost any sensible algorithm is probably fast enough. `O(2^n)` should be fine.
- n ~ 100: `O(n^4)` might be OK.
- n ~ 1000: `O(n^3)` might be OK.
- n ~ 10^4: `O(n^2)` might be OK, but don't rule out an `O(n log n)` solution.
- n ~ 10^5: `O(n log n)` might be OK, or you might need `O(n)`.
- n ~ 10^6: your algorithm needs to be `O(n)` or better.
- n >= 10^7: you should probably be looking for an algorithm which takes `O(log n)` or `O(1)` time.

For problems where you are answering many queries, take `n` to be the number of queries and divide the required complexity by `n` to get an estimate of what time complexity you need to achieve per query. In this case, at about 10^5 queries means you have to answer each query in at most logarithmic time, or preferably constant time.

You can also do some preprocessing before you start answering any queries, if there is a way to build a data structure which will help you answer many queries more efficiently; in this case, there is no data to pre-process, but perhaps we could preprocess e.g. the XORs of numbers between 1 and `x` for each `x`. However, unfortunately that's not going to be feasible for this problem because preprocessing such an array would take linear time, and our `x` values would have to go up to 10^15 to be useful.

This gives us two quite strong conclusions:

- We probably need to answer each query in logarithmic or constant time.
- It is infeasible to build a useful data structure to help us answer the queries.

So we can immediately reject the obvious algorithm which computes `O(r - l)` XOR operations to answer a single query - this will take linear time on the order of 10^15 operations, not constant time, so it's definitely not fast enough. That means you need to go completely back to the drawing board; the algorithm you have cannot be "simplified" to be made fast enough, you need a fundamentally different algorithm which exploits some mathematical fact in order to compute the answers without actually doing all of the XORs. Here are a few hints for getting an algorithm which takes logarithmic time per query:

- Finding the XOR of the numbers from 1 to `x` is a good subproblem to solve. It can be done by finding each bit separately; consider how many of the numbers between 1 and `x` have a given bit set, and whether that's odd or even.
- Finding the XOR of the even numbers from 1 to `x`, or the odd numbers from 1 to `x`, can be solved by reduction to the first subproblem.
- The XOR of the A values between `l` and `r` is the XOR of the result between 1 and `l-1`, and the result between 1 and `r`.

It turns out there is also a way to do it in constant time per query, but that is harder to find.